# Ubuntu 16.04 set up with google online account but no drive folder in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, drive, google, gnome-control-center

Pretty much as the question says. I followed the steps to set up the online accounts through system settings but my drive folder is not showing up on Nautilus.

Comment: Followed what steps? I have google-drive in nautilus on 2 different laptops in 16.04 so does work.  Did you do something like this - http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/use-gnome-318-google-drive-integration.html

Comment: Yes I followed those steps. I noticed that the options under the Google account (first and second image in the link you sent) is different to the options I'm presented with: [my screen](http://imgur.com/a/rhGTV).

Comment: That looks more like the unity-control panel. Try from terminal `gnome-control-center online-accounts` (- if you added google to the unity-control-panel it it appears you did  then maybe first open it & remove `unity-control-center credentials`

Comment: That's the ticket doug. Thanks very much for your help! :D

Comment: It would be good to have an accepted answer with this solution.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can answer your own question

Answer (score 22):

This is the solution that worked for me ([source](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/use-gnome-318-google-drive-integration.html)):

Install GNOME Control Center (GNOME System Settings) and GNOME Online Accounts:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
```

Open the GNOME Online Accounts:

```
gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

From there add your Google account and make sure "Files" is enabled:

[image: GNOME Online Accounts window]

You should now be able to access your Google Drive files from the Files (Nautilus) app which appears alongside other mounted drives and, in my case, is named with my email address.

Comment: This isn't working for me on Ubuntu 16.04. Everywhere I look online I see a screenshot like what you show, but my online accounts interface is different. Instead of just "Mail", "Calendar", etc. I have toggles for "Empathy", "Shotwell", "Evolution Data Server", etc. and the only Google Drive related one is "Google Drive search plugin". With everything enabled I still don't see the Google Drive files in Nautilus.

Comment: @Colin I thought the same, but as this answer suggests, you **should** install **this** gnome-control-center. The one you currently have is different (I know it looks similar. But it's different). Just tested it on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and **it is working**.
Note: Then you will have two, separate "Settings" apps but well... that's the price.

Comment: If it helps anyone else, you should use the terminal command to open the Gnome Control Center. After installing everything, you'll now have 'System Settings', 'Settings', 'Online Accounts', and 'Settings > Online Accounts'. Both Online Accounts options will let you connect to a Google Drive account, but only the 'Settings > Online Accounts' will work for syncing GDrive files

Comment: It's quite confusing to have two different online account interfaces.  Is there a way to remove one?

Comment: Something that might work is to run `/usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon --replace`. Kudos to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=203544

Comment: It's strange on Gnome ubuntu when you search for "online accouts" it shows exmpty box, but if you go there through CLI or settings -> online account, there they are.

Comment: I got this working on ubuntu 18.04. But I don't know how to access it from the cli or another application to open the files... Where is this mounted at?

Comment: Is there a way to authenticate a Google account in gnome-online-accounts via CLI?

Answer (score 6):

## Introduction

Sadly, there is no official Google Drive client yet. I'm assuming you want to access your Google Drive as a local folder.

*TLDR: Use a Fuse FS implementation to mount your Google Drive locally.*

[This site](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/mount-google-drive-in-linux-with-google.html) explains it better than I possibly can, but I'll write the minor instructions in case the link goes down.

## Installation

- Add the repository to your sources.
- Update your apt sources.
- Install google-drive-ocamlfuse

The following commands execute the above three steps respectively:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

## Usage

The following commands are to be run in a terminal.

- Authenticate google-drive-ocamlfuse with your Google account by simply running `google-drive-ocamlfuse`.
- Now, in the browser tab that opens, follow the instructions to authenticate.
- Create a new directory where you want the Google Drive to be mounted. For example, run `mkdir ~/gdrive` to create a new gdrive directory in your home directory.

The steps till now were just one-time tasks. From now on, you need to type the following command to mount your Drive:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive
```

Now you can access all your Drive documents inside that folder.

When you're done with everything, type `sudo umount ~/gdrive` to unmount the Drive.

## Extra

You might want to automatically mount the Drive when you login. To do this, run 'Startup Applications' and add a new entry to it with the command:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive
```

Comment: google-drive-ocamlfuse has some malfunction. For ex. when sync files then google drive doesn't recognise the type of file anymore (this is what I got in 5 sec. of testing).

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of [James's answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/867520/527764) unsuccessfully. A certificate update worked for me:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem you're having is that there is a Unity online account manager installed in 16.04 by default. (Several mentions of this in the comments led me to figure out how to make it work...)

You can add the Gnome online account manager, but if you don't remove the Unity online account manager first you won't get the Gnome online account options even if you install them and run a Gnome desktop...

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center unity-control-center-signon unity-control-center-faces credentials
```

Then you can install the Gnome tools and it works when you look in System Settings...

```
  sudo apt-get install  gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
```

Now go to System Settings => Online Accounts and add a Google account... Then you get the file mount for Google Drive in Nautilus (if you've enabled the check box).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no Google Drive Linux client at the moment as you may see [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en-419/drive/download/). As far as I know what you get when you sync with your google account in ubuntu is the ability to search google docs in the dash but nothing more.

If you want to use google drive with Ubuntu you can use [inSync](https://www.insynchq.com/) which is a google drive client for linux (and mac os, windows and raspberry pi),for me it works flawless.

I hope my answer have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `gvfs-backends` packages solved this issue for me.

Comment: Great answer, this one worked for me!