# gnome-online-accounts Hanging (Ubuntu's google account connecting failing)

Tags: gnome, google-drive

I have tried to **connect** the Ubuntu 18.04 to my **Google Drive** by this instruction (based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838956/ubuntu-16-04-set-up-with-google-online-account-but-no-drive-folder-in-nautilus) instruction, times ago!):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center gnome-online-accounts
gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

But it has a problem to connect to my Google accounts and **now**, I have a problem by **new Gmail's ID**  like shown below (on **the last step of activation**):

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing a window with garbled dots and lines.